# Python excluding indexes from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, selection

I have an array

```
a=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```

I selected the 2nd and 3rd element with

```
a[[1,2]]
```

obtaining

```
array([10, 20])
```

How do I select the other elements of `a` except the elements I've already selected?

That is, I want to obtain:

```
array([0, 30, 40, 50, 60])
```

Logically, should be something like

```
a[![1,2]]
```

Comment: There is a filter function that does that => [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). You can just Google, "Python 3 filter".

Comment: Tag `numpy` if that is what you're asking about.

Comment: `a` as shown (but not named) is a list.  `a[[1,2]]` gives an error.  If `a` really is a numpy array, you should show that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
a=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

b = a[1:3]
c =[x for x in a if x not in b]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
[10, 20]
[0, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```

If order does not matter, you can stuff the list in a set and use [these set operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):
`yourSet.union(otherSet)` , `yourSet.intersect(otherSet)` , `yourSet.difference(otherSet)` , etc

Comment: This uses plain old Python.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yes? If you have numpy and a hammer and see a nail - what would you do?

Comment: Smack it with the numpy of course!

Answer (score 0):

In case on python 2.7, the easiest solution is that:

```
a=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
c=[1,2]
values = [a[i] for i, x in enumerate(a) if i not in c]
print values
[0, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```